# How access to Wordpress using a Webview?

Tags: android, wordpress

I have an Android application, for use it I need to log in. In this application  I have an activity that contains a WebView, in this WebView I display a WordPress web page however, when I access to the WebView this shows the wp-login and I need to retype the credentials and this process is not necessary because the credentials between the application and the site are the same.

Do you know how can access without writing the authentication two times?

Comment: use javascript. but also having an app that requires you to log into a wordpress admin panel seems super wonkey